# Unable to migrate in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-migrations

**model.py**

```
class Staff(models.Model):
   organization = models.ForeignKey(
        Organization, related_name='staff_organization', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

I am trying to add the new field in the database table. II just added the address field. I got following error:

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Project\AIT Project\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line    
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Project\AIT Project\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Project\AIT Project\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\Project\AIT Project\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Project\AIT Project\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Project\AIT Project\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "D:\Project\AIT Project\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "D:\Project\AIT Project\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Project\AIT Project\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\Project\AIT Project\project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user_email_1c89df09_uniq" already exists
```

Comment: Is this project for learning purpose?

Answer (score 1):

try to run

```
python manage.py migrate <yourappname> zero
```

then go into you migration folder and delete all the file except pycache and initpy
then again

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

this has to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

One option is to delete auth_user_email_1c89df09_uniq constraint from db in any database management system. i did it with pgadmin 2.